# Sum not working in column beside arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a column which won't sum? it sits beside a column with an array formula how is a sum done in this case?

This is my formula in  `C3`:

```
ArrayFormula(query({M8Report!A2:T,arrayformula(left(regexreplace(M8Report!N2:N, "\n|\r", ""),150))},"Select Col5,Col2,Col1,Col21,Col3 Where (Col4 = 'Work Order') order by Col5", -1))
```

in B I have entered integer values in B1 I have `=sum(B3:B)` and the result is always 0 if instead in B1 I use `B3+B4+B5+etc..` I get the correct result...

..Tried everything I can think of and same issue sum =0
since C is dynamic I need a way to sum all of the values in B
..any ideas would be helpful

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet?  I have not had a problem using sum() on a column populated via an arrayformula().

Comment: sure ..https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xbGsDRXMZoFi5D44gl4Xh2mpEkL19Fw-3Uhy8o5aGPo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your sample sheet your formula is:

```
= { QUERY ; { "TOTAL" , SUM(B3:B) } }
```

Change it to:

```
=CONCAT("TOTAL ", SUM(B3:B))
```

The error has to do with your use of the {}, which is used to define an array literal.  You just want to have 2 strings merged where one is the sum of the values.  Also note that you may want to use B4:B instead since B3 is a header for the data below that.

Last, make sure the data is Numbers.  The original data is formatted as Plain Text so SUM() has nothing to add.

Comment: the real problem is with Sum(B3:B) the result is always 0 that is the vexing one...

Comment: After copying the file (it was read only) I did some testing and I see that the original data is formated aas Plain Text.  Change it to Automatic or Number and you can use =SUM()

Comment: HA! you got it.... on my original sheet the format was number when i made a copy for you it switched to plain text ... so i converted the original (number formatted column) to text then switched back to a number format and bingo all good! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

to ditch formatting issues you can do:

```
={"Total", SUMPRODUCT(B5:B)}
```

[image: 0]